# Question about a proof concerning probability generating functions.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, generating-functions, moment-generating-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable with $\mathbb P(X\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\})=1$ The probability generating function of $X$ is defined by
$$
\rho(s) = \mathbb E[s^X] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb P(X=k)s^k+\begin{cases}
0,& \text{ if } 0\leqslant s <1\\
\mathbb P(X=\infty),& \text{ if } s=1.
\end{cases}
$$
The claim in question is:
$$
\mathbb E \left[\prod_{m=0}^{n-1}(X-m)\right] = \rho^{(n)}(1), \ n=1,2,\ldots
$$
We can assume that $\lim_{s\uparrow 1}\rho(s)=1$, as otherwise the claim is trivial. By definition,
$$
\rho'(1) = \lim_{s\uparrow 1}\frac{1-\rho(s)}{1-s} = \lim_{s\uparrow 1} \mathbb E\left[\frac{1-s^X}{1-s}\right].
$$
What I don't understand is the following:

> As $s$ increases to $1$ through an arbitrary sequence, the nonnegative random variables $(1-s^X)/(1-s)$ form an increasing sequence whose limit is $X$.

The author gives no justification for this claim, and I don't see how it follows. Could I get a hint as to why this is true?

Comment: I think I see. The series expansion for $\frac{1-s^x}{1-s}$ is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(s-1)^n}{(n+1)!}\prod_{j=0}^n (x-j),$$ so as $s\to1$ we are simply left with $x$. I wonder why the author omitted this detail.